# problemas al instalar npm i angular-cropperjs

Tags: angular

estoy intentando instalar esta librería pero me da estos errores. ¿Alguien me puede ayudar?

> npm i angular-cropperjs
> npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
> npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! While resolving: client@0.0.0
> npm ERR! Found: @angular/common@12.0.1
> npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/common
> npm ERR!   @angular/common@"~12.0.0" from the root project
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
> npm ERR! peer @angular/common@"^6.0.0-rc.0 || ^6.0.0" from angular-cropperjs@1.0.2
> npm ERR! node_modules/angular-cropperjs
> npm ERR!   angular-cropperjs@"*" from the root project
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
> npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
> npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! See C:\Users\gabri\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> npm ERR!     C:\Users\gabri\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2021-05-21T15_20_22_470Z-debug.log

Comment: Sería de gran ayuda si nos pudieras dar más detalles de que es lo que has intentado 
 y que versión de nodejs tienes

Comment: Tengo el nodejs actualizado a la última versión y el angular también

Answer (score -1):

- Verifica que tu versión de nodejs sea la LTS y no la actual

ya que revisaste esto prueba con esto.

- eliminando la carpeta `node_modules`.
- Corre `npm cache verify`.
- Corre `npm install`.

Comment: efectivamente tengo la version lts v-14.17.0 y npm v-7.13